# Pegadinha do Primeiro de Abril?

Tags: suporte, bug, novo-recurso

Utilizando o stackoverflow em ingles apareceu esse banner quando eu copiei um código:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao clicar em saiba mais ele exibe um banner:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Achei muito legal.
Para poder ativar eu acho que copiei umas 10x (apertei o botão <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/31/the-key-copy-paste/

Comment: @hkotsubo até pro blog a brincadeira se propaga, fico pensando se teve gente que levou a sério. PS: se fosse para eu comprar, seria pra quebrar pisando em cima, já que isso ai (apesar de brincadeira) é um verdadeiro símbolo para o que o SO se tornou :)

Comment: Só não comprei porque não vem o Ctrl no teclado. Do que adianta as letras C e V sem o Ctrl?

Comment: @Woss o ícone da SO é o "Ctrl", entendeu? Eles querem nos "ConTRoLar" ⃤ .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No site "principal" ("carro-chefe") da empresa é comum terem coisas assim, propagar isso para os "builds" do diversos sites ([atualmente 176 site](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest)) que a empresa tem hoje não é fácil e provavelmente não é prioridade, até mesmo os chapéus que é algo padrão de ocorrer todos anos, na ultima vez deu BUG em alguns sites. Então é improvável que seja um novo recurso para os diversos sites.

No entanto eu não posso afirmar com toda certeza, talvez um CM apareça e diga que estará ativado em breve, mas pelo horário do dia não acho que vá acontecer.

Respondendo ao titulo da pergunta (não tenho certeza se perguntou isso ou se era só um pedido de novo recurso apenas):

> Pegadinha do Primeiro de Abril?

Sim, é uma pegadinha da data, veja mensagem na hora que você tenta comprar:

[image: April fools do SOen]